# Mysql select all data from one colum

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select all data from one column from my database. Is there a way to do it like this? :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM summary WHERE Domain= '-ALL-' AND Name LIKE '%$id_name%' AND Date_rep='$time' AND System='$id_sys'");
```

This code above is what I use, but I need to make 'Domain' column to show EVERY data in that column (Not only one name but all names in that column).

PS: I know I should use mysqli. But this time I am doing it in Mysql.

Comment: `SELECT \`column_name\` FROM ...`

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statement

Comment: `System='$id_sys'`? is this row id?   if yes then it will give you one record otherwise all possible records will come because of like. you can do like `SELECT * FROM summary where id =?`

Comment: Yes Im using it to filter the database, for example when user input is System1, it will show only System1 in the table

Comment: Why do you have conditions in your query when you say you want all data?

Comment: I need to select from specific table (i have multiple tables in there) and from that specific table I need to make id_name to select all the data from that column.

Comment: *"I know I should use mysqli. But this time I am doing it in Mysql."*: so you knowingly go for a set of functions which are deprecated, unmaintained since 2013, and not supported in any of the PHP 7 releases?

Comment: Sumary is one table: what do you mean *"I have multiple tables in there"*? Are you referring to the Performance Schema in MySql?

Comment: Im using php 5.5. So ya im using deprecated mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select column_name from summary;   // do not put any condition so that query can return all row for the specified column
```

Comment: But I still need to put others in there (id_sys, id_name..) so somebody can search for date, name and system

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!
Instead of using *, enter a column_name. So, if you want to display data of one column without any where clause, you can do like this:

```
select column_name from table_name;
```

However, if you want to get data using the where clause:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT '$column_name' FROM summary WHERE Domain= '-ALL-' AND Name LIKE '%$id_name%' AND Date_rep='$time' AND System='$id_sys'");
```

Comment: Im using it in my html table. This doesnt fix the issue, because I still need to show EVERY row with that name. And then when somebody select the name, it will show everything with the name he selected.

Comment: I think we all are giving you the wrong answer because of the ambiguous question statement. Can you please share your schema with us and tell exactly what is that you want? I think you want to change how the DOMAIN column appears, somewhat like that! Edit your question and add the necessary details in it!